# BadImageFormat in Web .Net Core 3.1 project with CLR .Net Core Library(C++/CLI)

Tags: c#, c++-cli, asp.net-core-webapi

I have get two projects: Web .Net Core C#(3.1) and CLR .Net Core(3.1 C++/CLI). I build&compile x64 architecture in two projects. But I Can't load my Lib => BadImageFormat for this Lib and An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. I add assembly link for my C++/CLI dll. Maybe I must add Ijwhost.dll from C++/CLI directory to my Web C# directory. How I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. Need add ljwhost.dll in host C# directory. It's work!!! For x32 architecture you must used x32 .Net Core package. Don't use AnyCPU.

For example:

[From this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqV7E.png)
====>
[To this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6zBG.png)